# c++ - initializing an array member with aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate, braces, aggregate-initialization

With this code:

```
struct Structure {
    int a;
    char b[4];
};

void function() {
    int a = 3;
    char b[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
}
```

Can I initialize `Structure` with the values of `a` and `b` using aggregate initialization?
I tried `Structure{a, b}`, however that gives me the error `cannot initialize an array element of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'char [4]'`

Comment: if you change both `char b[]` by `std::array<char, 4>`, yes. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ac7cfe90b9a75e0)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct S {
    int a;
    char b[4];
};

int main() {
    S s = { 1, {2,3,4,5} };
}
```

Edit: Just re-read your question - no, you can't do that. You can't initialise an array with another array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with **parameter-pack-expansion** I think you can, like this:

```
struct Structure {
    int a;
    char b[4];
};

template< typename... I, typename... C>
void function(I... a, C... b) {
    Structure s = { a..., b... }; // <- here -> a = 1 and b = 'a','b','c','d'
    std::cout << s.a << '\n';
    for( char chr : s.b ) std::cout << chr << ' ';
}

int main(){
    function( 1, 'a','b','c','d' );
}
```

The output:

```
1
a b c d
```